# BORLNDMM.DLL не был найден - с++ builder xe

Tags: c++builder

Можно ли, чтоб откомпилированные программы С++ builder XE запускались там, где не установлен он сам.

В Project->Options->Packages убрал галочку с Build with runtime packages.

Все равно не работает вылетает

> ошибка: BORLNDMM.DLL не был найден.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно поставить еще одну галочку в Project->Oprions->C++ Linker->Link With Dynamic RTL